# Sumar elementos de listas y comparar resultado python

Tags: python

[image: Ayuda con este ejercicio por favor, debe haber un metodo mas python que anidar fors]
La intencion es encontrar la suma correcta entre los elementos y devolver sus indices.

Answer (score 0):

simplemente podrías crear una función, (o método en tu caso ya que usarías una clase) que agarre cada numero de tu lista y intente sumarlo con cada uno de los otros números a ver si es igual al pivote. No sé si me expliqué bien, pero te lo explico en código:

```
def get_combinaciones(numeros, pivote):
    combinaciones = []
    for i in range(len(numeros)):
        for j in range(0, len(numeros)):
            if i == j:
                continue
            n1 = numeros[i]
            n2 = numeros[j]
            if n1 + n2 == pivote:
                combinaciones.append([i, j])
    return combinaciones
```

Entonces para usarlo simplemente haces:

```
numeros = [10, 20, 10, 40, 5, 25, 25]
pivote = 50
print(get_combinaciones(numeros, pivote))
```

Y el resultado sería: `[[0, 3], [2, 3], [3, 0], [3, 2], [5, 6], [6, 5]]` que tiene otro orden, pero en realidad es lo mismo.

Espero haberte ayudado!

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente el mismo método de @vschiaffino, pero con compresión de listas

```
lista = [10, 20, 30, 40, 5, 25, 25]
for r in [[i, j] for i in range(len(lista)) for j in range(len(lista)) if i != j and lista[i] + lista[j] == 50]:
    print(r, lista[r[0]] + lista[r[1]])
```

Produce

```
[0, 3] 50
[1, 2] 50
[2, 1] 50
[3, 0] 50
[5, 6] 50
[6, 5] 50
```